# Java How do i repeat sort until no swaps are done in bubblesort?

Tags: java, sorting, bubble-sort

I am taking 10 elements and performing a bubble sort on them. I want to add an algorithm that repeats the sort until no swaps are needed to make this more efficient.
**Essentially I want to:**

- repeat until no swaps done in a pass
- For elements 1 to (n-1)
- compare contents of element value 1 with the contents of the next value
- if value 1 is greater than value 2
- then swap the values

This is what I have done so far :

````
    {

        //create array
        int[] iList = new int[10];
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        //takes in array input for 10 numbers
        
        System.out.println("Enter a array of numbers ");

        
        for(int i = 0; i< 10; i++ ) 
        {
            int num = i + 1;
            System.out.println("Enter number " + num);
            iList[i] = sc.nextInt();
            
        }

        //Bubble sorts the array
        
        System.out.println("The array =");

        for(int a = 0; a < iList.length; a++ )
        {
          for(int b = a+1; b < iList.length; b++) 
          {
                if(iList[a] > iList[b])
                {
                    int iTemp = iList[a];
                    iList[a] = iList[b];
                    iList[b] = iTemp;   
                    
                }
                  System.out.println("Progress = " + Arrays.toString(iList) );
           }    
        
        }
        
    } ```
````

Comment: create a `bool` to store if it has ever been swapped in the iteration. `break` if not

Comment: at the beginning of the outer loop introduce a `boolean` variable, change the value of  that `boolean` variable inside the if, check if that variable changed before the outer loop ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my implementation :

```
public static void sort(int[] nums) {
        boolean isSwapped;
        int size = nums.length - 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            isSwapped = false;
            for (int j = 0; j < size - i; j++) {
                if (nums[j] > nums[j+1]) {
                    int temp = nums[j];
                    nums[j] = nums[j + 1];
                    nums[j + 1] = temp;
                    isSwapped = true;
                }
            }
            if (!isSwapped) break;
        }

        System.out.println("Sorted Array: " + Arrays.toString(nums));
    }
```